# cat output in the case of if else statement

Tags: shell-script, shell

```
os_version=$(cat /etc/issue |grep Ubuntu)
if $os_version
then
echo found
else
echo notfound
fi
```

When I tried it on an Ubuntu machine it says
./test: line 2: Ubuntu: command not found
notfound

This works for me, But I want to assign it to a variable

```
if cat /etc/issue |grep Ubuntu
then
echo found
else
echo notfound
fi
```

Comment: What did you *intend* with the "if" test? By default, it expects to execute a command and test that return code, which is why it told you it tried to execute a command that started with "Ubuntu...". Are you interested in whether /etc/issue contains the word "Ubuntu" or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: I am interested to know if /etc/issue contains Ubuntu,I would like to assign it to a variable and check

Comment: If you want to know whether or not /etc/issue contains Ubuntu, why do you want to assign anything to a variable?  Just check the status of `grep`.

Comment: Of course, if the "Ubuntu" in your login banner is coming from an `\S` in `/etc/issue`, none of this will pick it up.  (-:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `if` statement runs a *command*, and checks its exit status.
Using `$os_version` as a command works by expanding it, and running the resulting command line. So if the variable contains `Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS \n \l`, it'll try to to run a command called `Ubuntu` with the arguments `18.04.1`, `LTS`, etc.

You probably want to use

```
if [ -n "$os_version" ]; then
    ...
fi
```

to check if the variable is empty or not (`[ -n "$var" ]` is true if it's not empty, while `[ -z "$var" ]` if the variable is empty).

Alternatively, you could use the `grep` within the `if` statement itself as you did in the edit, and set a variable there:

```
distro=unknown
if grep -q Ubuntu < /etc/issue; then
    distro=ubuntu
fi
# ... later
if [ "$distro" = ubuntu ]; then
    # do something Ubuntu-specific
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -q Ubuntu /etc/issue && echo found || echo not found
```

Comment: See also `case $(lsb_release -si) in (Ubuntu) ...;; (Debian) ...; esac`